# Excel color is abnormal

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

The Excel setting is Dark Gray, and it turns out to be super black inexplicably when opened today, and there are some dotted lines in the table.

I checked online and there are several methods, but none of them worked.

1. Open the print preview -> Excel 2019 I can't find where to turn off this thing (but I didn't get ctrl + p, and this problem will occur when I create a new table)
2. The page break is displayed -> this can be turned off, but only the dotted line is not displayed (what I want is to restore the dark gray)

Word and PowerPoint are not affected. Does anyone know why?

The blackened Excel UI seems a little different from the black Office Theme.

Excel when Office Theme is Dark Grey:

[image]

Word when Office Theme is Dark Grey:

[image]

PowerPoint when Office Theme is Dark Grey:

[image]

Comment: I ran into a related problem and wrote about it in https://superuser.com/questions/1688360/excel-appearance-changed-new-theme-seems-broken . You can also notice that Excel's UI layout is different. In the official docs, it says this is how Office is supposed to look like, with the colors and all, since july 2021.

Comment: @theultramage After 5 days without any progress, I reported this problem to the Microsoft community. The solution is modify some values in regedit (in fact, the problem may be caused by my careless operations). You can see if it helps you, the page is https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-color-is-abnormal/12bd71ad-50a2-44fd-b7fd-dfb37046b119

Comment: Thank you, Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRefresh was the one causing the issues I described. Should help you as well. For the future, I don't know if it's possible to easily install additional User Interface themes to modify the colors. Hopefully there will be a way to do that.